# How to validate form in c# code before taking values to process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

I want to validate a form before submitting to server which contains 6 textboxes and one dropdown box.My requirement is  out of 5 text boxes  any one is sufficient ,which are `txtEid.Text` ,`txtAccountNo.Text`,`txtPlot.Text`,`txtLongitude.Text(X),txtYlatitude.Text(Y)`.Here `txtLongitude.Text(X),txtYlatitude.Text(Y)`both required together.  if none of them given and dropdonwbox `drpBranch` only selected then a textbox `txtPlot` is required along with dropdownbox.If none of above given and `txtBlock` text box has values then `txtPlot` is required along with `txtBlock` .
What i did is  like shown below .But the problem in that code is if `drpBranch` or 
`txtBlock` and any one of the 5 text boxes give in the first have values ,then no need to wait for `txtPlot.Text`.how to achieve this logic?

```
private bool ValidateControls()
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "";
        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(drpBranch.SelectedValue)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPlot.Text)))
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter Plot number to get the Network details";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                return false;
        }
        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBlock.Text)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPlot.Text)))
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter Plot number to get the Network details";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                return false;
        }
        //else
        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEid.Text)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAccountNo.Text)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPlot.Text)) && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLongitude.Text)) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtYlatitude.Text))))
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter either EID or Account Number or Plot Number or X,Y co ordinates  to get the Network details";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you rephrase this:`But the problem in that code is if drpBranch or txtBlock and any one of the 5 text boxes give in the first have values ,then no need to wait for txtPlot.Text.how to achieve this logic?`. And is there a reason you are not doing the validation on the client side?

Comment: @ShareYourKnowledge as i said any one of the 5 textboxes is sufficient to process the form,So some body selects dropdown   value then no need to wait for txtPlot.Text .But if none of the 5 textboxes value has given then txtPlot.Text is required to do the process

Comment: How about adding the text of all the 5 textboxes into an array or a list. Then loop through the list to look for not null and implement the rest of the logic

Comment: @ShareYourKnowledge can you post the code

Comment: the below answer is obviously not complete but it should give an idea as to how you can check all 5 textboxes for nulls and only then decide whether you need to check the txtPlot textbox

Comment: sorry but i have to agree with @ShareYourKnowledge can rephrase what you want. its hard to follow... what you are saying which is probably why your finding writing the validation harder than it needs to be.

Comment: the below answer is obviously not complete, but if you could update your question with the formatting i use in my example answer... then im sure we will get to the bottom of this.

Comment: from what i understand the problem is not that difficult, its just a matter of understanding the conditions, their dependency and priority. I provided an answer to give an idea as to how a part of your problem can be solved via a loop, the rest you got pretty much figured out

Comment: i have posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it in simpler way

```
private bool ValidateControls()
{
    lblMessage.Text = "";

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEid.Text)
     && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAccountNo.Text)
     && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPlot.Text)
     && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLongitude.Text)
     && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtYlatitude.Text))
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(drpBranch.SelectedValue) 
          && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPlot.Text))
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter Plot number to get the Network details";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            return false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBlock.Text) 
          && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPlot.Text))
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter Plot number to get the Network details";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = @"Please enter either EID or Account Number 
                                or Plot Number or X,Y co ordinates
                                to get the Network details";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a list of string
// Add all your 5 textbox values into the list
// create a boolean variable to check if All textboxes are empty
// Loop through list
// If atlist one txtValue is not empty, exit loop and set bool value    to    false

    List<string> txtValues = new List<string>();
    // Add all your 5 textboxes
    txtValues.Add(txtBlock.Text);

    bool allEmpty = true;

    foreach(string txtValue in txtValues){
          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtValue)){

                allEmpty=false;
                // exit for loop
          }
    }
    if(allEmpty && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(drpBranch.SelectedValue)){
        // check the txtPlot values
    }
```

Comment: what about dropdownbox value?

Comment: so if all 5 textboxes are empty and dropdownbox is selected then check txtPlot.

Comment: i have posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

**NB :Obviously this is not complete im trying to get clarity...**

```
1.txtEid.Text
2.txtAccountNo.Text
3.txtPlot.Text
4.txtLongitude.Text(X) (require if 5)
5.txtYlatitude.Text(Y) (require if 4)

6. dropdown ("Please select" = -1)
7. dropdownText

if(dropdown != -1) Ie they choose to use the dropdown.
{
    if(dropdownText != "")
    {

    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please enter the dropdownText";
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        return false;
    }
}

//validate both field where given..if the other was.
//there is a smarter way to write this...
if(txtLongitude != "" || txtYlatitude != "")
{
    if(txtLongitude == "" && txtYlatitude == "")
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please give both Longitude and  latitude";
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        return false;
    }
}

//your wording got confusing..., please update and ill update the answer.
```

by your wording:

> question is simple any of the 5 textbox value is sufficient to process
>   form.If none of them given then we have to go with txtplot required
>   for either dropdown or txtblock entries

```
 if(txtEid.Text != ""
   && txtAccountNo.Text != ""
   && txtPlot.Text != ""
   && txtLongitude.Text != ""
   && txtYlatitude.Text != "")
{
  //form is valid
}
else
{
    //go with txtplot required either dropdown or txtblock entries
}
```

Can you now see why it is confusing for me to follow?

Comment: question is simple any  of the 5 textbox value is sufficient to process form.If none of them given then we have to go with txtplot required for either dropdown or txtblock entries

Comment: i have posted my answer